# Contribution Report with total paid and balance fields?

Tags: civicontribute, civireport

Since partial payments were introduced in civicrm 4.5 is there any report available (core of extension) which allows to use "total paid" and "balance" as fields and filters?

Comment: I think we don't have a option of selecting "Total paid and balance" in a core report as fields and filters